# Accessing mobile features by including cordova.js/phonegap.js in jsps

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I built a native android application using cordova and jquery mobile .

On start , welcome page is shown and from that page i call a url hosted on some server.
Based on the business logic server returns some jsp (designed using jQM).

So now I am viewing those jsps in my in-app browser. Since jsps are designed using jquery mobile it doesn't appear that my application is running on browser but it seems to be working fine. I am happy with it.

But my question is, is it possible to access native mobile features from these jsps, if I include cordova.js/phoegap.js in them?